# race condition with redis session

Tags: ruby, session, race-condition

I have the problem that my software has critical data stored in the session.

Since I'm using ajax and the user can simply open the software in several tabs there WILL be parallel requests.
Limiting it to one request at a time is unfortunately not possible.

My original attempt to solve this problem was to use an after_filter in my application_controller to call a method that would detect changes other workers made and merge them into its own session object before saving it.

Unfortunately that did mitigate my problem but not solve it completely.
It seems to me that between my after_filter and the middleware that actually saves my session, which is ActionDispatch::Session::RedisStore, there is still a gap big enough for another worker write his own session.

I cannot think of any other solution to close this gap but this one:

1. Write a class that inherits from the middleware
2. teach it to execute the "merge code" in get_session and set_session
3. replace the original middleware with my class by config.middleware.swap

Before I do this I would like to aks for opinions and advice or, ideally, a better solution. Messing with the middleware seems too dangerous to me to do without asking for advice first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the data in session is critical, I think it's better to synchronize requests from each user, while keep concurrency between different users.

For example, you can fire up several rails processes, each listening its own port, and provide a load balancer (e.g. Nginx) above those processes.
A load balancer with session sticky feature is perfect, but IP hash is also acceptable.